# Static code Analysis tool for C Source Code with MISRA Compliance to embed within C# Project

Tags: c#, c, code-analysis, misra

I have a Console Application written in C#. 
Here, I should embed a Static Code Analyser tool within C# Console Application which should analyse C Code.(here, .c and .h file(s) will be given as input through command line which should undergo Static Code Analysis) as per MISRA rule-set.

Do we have any free tool which we can embed within C# project and perform Static Code analysis of C program within C# project?